# How would I query this data frame (SQL) to calculate the rate of change of raw visits in 2020 months to their 2019 months?

Tags: sql

(2020 raw visits/2019 raw visits) * 100

So it would only have 4 rows for January, February, March, April. I just was confused how to accomplish this since the values I want to divide by are in the same column. Any advice would be much appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7mKI.png)

Comment: Please show what you've tried, and what version of SQL (mySQL, Oracle, SQL-Server, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
(count(2020 raw visits)/count(2019 raw visits)) * 100
group by Column_Month
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (count(CASE WHEN YEAR=2020 THEN visits ELSE NULL END)/count(CASE WHEN YEAR = 
        2019 THEN visits ELSE NULL END)) * 100
FROM TABLE
WHERE YEAR IN(2019,2020)
group by Column_Month
```